# getting issue in sending pagination value in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using material-UI pagination I am sending page number in API mean I am getting data according to page number what's happening in the first time it's going properly but when I click 2 or another number it's not taking that same number it's taking the previous number at the first time then again I click on 2 then it will take 2 in API click but when I console data it's coming properly mean  in this console coming data property
`console.log("page", page)`
but in the API function console
`console.log("page1", page)`
taking the previous number and sending same in API call

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    setPage(value);
  };

  console.log("page",page)
  const pageChange = () => {
      console.log("page1",page)
      axios
        .get(
          `${DJANGO_SERVER_ADDRESS}/file/?screen=first&ID=${uploadData.ID}&page=${page}`
        )
        .then(
          (res) => {
            console.log("csv", res.data);
            setCsvdata(res.data);
          },
          (err) => {}
        );
  };
```

```
<p>{page}</p>
<Box  mb={2} ml={20} mr={5} pl={20} pr={5}>
   <Pagination
     onClick={(e) => {
       pageChange();
     }}
     count={10}
     page={page}
     onChange={handleChange}
     variant="outlined"
     />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a call before your state is getting updated. You may try calling an API using `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log("page1",page)
      axios
        .get(
          `${DJANGO_SERVER_ADDRESS}/file/?screen=first&ID=${uploadData.ID}&page=${page}`
        )
        .then(
          (res) => {
            console.log("csv", res.data);
            setCsvdata(res.data);
          },
          (err) => {}
        );
},[page]);
```